# How can I prevent \ifnum to be ignored?

Tags: conditionals, counters, plain-tex

So I have the following code:

```
\newcount\x\x\i
\ifnum\x<3 \advance\x1 \fi
\the\x
\bye
```

which I call from the command line with `pdftex '\def\i{9}\input test.tex'`
This puts out 10 (or \i + 1), meaning that the `\ifnum` is ignored and instead the `\advance` is always executed. How to make TeX properly process at the `\ifnum`?

Comment: are you redefining `\i`?

Comment: @erreka Yes, in the command line

Comment: just make sure you don't use (even indirectly) a dotless i anywhere in your source.

Comment: @erreka I know of the dangers of redefining commands, but by my knowledge I have never used a dotless i yet :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\x\i` expands `\i` in search for digits to form an integer, so it goes on and expands also `\ifnum`; in this situation, `\x` is still set to 0. Note that there is *no* space after `\i` and the newline gets ignored.

Add `\relax` or `\space` after `\i`.

```
\newcount\x\x\i\relax
\ifnum\x<3 \advance\x1 \fi
\the\x
\bye
```

Alternatively, a blank line is good as well

```
\newcount\x\x\i

\ifnum\x<3 \advance\x1 \fi
\the\x
\bye
```

because the inserted `\par` token will stop the lookup for new digits.

Let's see what happens with your code. First TeX defines a new counter `\x` and `\newcount\x` disappears. Next, upon seeing `\x`, TeX knows it has to perform an assignment; no `=` follows (which would disappear as well) and `\i` is expanded; however, by rule, TeX will continue to expand tokens until finding something that cannot be interpreted as a decimal digit (an explicit token of category code 12 and character code corresponding to a digit from 0 to 9).

The expansion of `\ifnum` consists in two steps; first the test is performed and, in this case it returns true, because the assignment has not yet been completed; then the conditional disappears together with the test and the true text is left in place (otherwise anything up to the matching `\else` or `\fi` would be skipped over). Thus we have

```
\x=9 \advance\x1 \fi
```

The space after `9` stops the expansion and, by rule, is ignored. Then `\x` is assigned the value 9 and advanced. Next `\fi` is expanded, but its expansion is empty.

With `\i\relax`, the assignment is performed and then `\ifnum` is examined.

Comment: If \ifnum is also expanded, does that mean that \ifnum is ignored, or that \ifnum checks and sees \x to be 0?

Comment: @SimonKlaver I added the full description.